# Cloning/Pushing/Pulling from bitbucket repository give error: 403

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying to push changes to my existing repository on bitbucket, but it give me the following response: "Server returned with error:403".
I have tried pushing to the repository through ssh, but it takes forever and no response is generated.
I have also tried cloning the repo. again fresh, but the same problem.
I have also tried changing the origin -url through git command but that also didn't help.

Comment: there can be git version miss match.....
I would suggest you update git once. maybe it will resolve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP status 403 is "unauthorized" - your credentials are valid for connecting to Bitbucket, but you don't have that type of access to that repo.

Are you certain you have access to that repo? Are you using your regular credentials or an app password?